# Displaying data in a table with JOIN

Tags: php, mysqli

I have re written my question as i can not post a new one due to down votes....

as you can tell i was trying to display data in a table format and was wrongly advised to use some code which i was to fault i should have researched the code before using it.

but its a lesson that i have learnt:)

new question

i have taken the answers below to try to rectify the issue and now have a new question based on my origanal one

i am trying to make *clients_id* from the table **repair_jobs** appear as the *name* from the table **contacts**

but i am having no luck
i have got 2 sql querices is this worng?

the 1st

```
$query = "select * from repair_jobs";
```

this helps me display he informaion i need and works

this is the 2nd

```
$query = "SELECT repair_jobs.client_id, contacts.name
FROM repair_jobs
INNER JOIN contacts
ON repair_jobs.client_id=contacts.name";
```

under that i have this to try to display the name of the client

```
echo "<td>{$client_id}</td>";
```

but it is only displaying the number and not the data i need

Comment: "Why my code doesn't work" is an offtopic question here, mind you

Comment: as you posted your comment i was already changing the end of my question due to it sounded blunt and rude. sorry

Comment: Rephrasing the same question using another words doesn't make it valid one. It is no because rudeness but because offtopic.

Comment: i have researched my question, and i am sure i wont be the only one with this issue. its a valid question as i know the issue thats causing this as i posted it in my question so why is this offtopic?

Comment: Nope, you are only one with such a ridiculous setup. Someone who told you to do such things like `$_REQUEST['id'] = $client_id;` did you a disservice.

Comment: thank you for your such warm words towards me. well pardon me i am trying to learn this and the hands on approach seems to work better for me than sitting reading books. if that is incorrect why is it wrong and what is the right way of doing things. if you could explain to me i might learn something.

Comment: this site is not a forum where people chat and learn and socialize and says warm words to each other. but rather a question-and-answer service. But question have to be *answerable* to fit here. "Please read my code and tell me what's wrong with it" have not.

Comment: i completely understand what your saying apart from i am asking why this problem is arising if its a simple answer there shouldn't be a issue, but reading your answer maybe there are more issues with the question than i first thought.

Comment: if it was indeed simple question, there would be a dozen answers already, mind you. In fact, *nobody* actually knows what's wrong with your code or have means to know.

Comment: i have re written my question regarding JOIN

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something extremely strange.

I don't understand where did you get that idea of multiple includes, but it is obviously wrong. So, quit it and make your code in 2 files max:

One to get your data.
And one to display it.

Comment: thumbs up :) the only reason i was doing it this way is because i don't know how to call data depending on the value of a column in one of the tabels. there is a field named client_id which is the same as the id in the table contacts can you see why i was trying to get this to work

Comment: Why do you want to use include? Can't you make it without?

Comment: because one php file is a maths code to show the total value and the other is one to display the client name as its using a different table and both using id to identify the data i need

Comment: it is not a valid reason. why can't you do your math and get username in the same file?

Comment: Not to mention that you apparently have to get the name using JOIN instead of doing another query

Comment: mind pointing me in the right direction regarding a basic tutorial on JOIN?

Comment: thanks for the heads up :) i have re written my question regarding JOIN